# creating installer with multiple applications with vb project

Tags: vb.net

i have published my project and exe file has been created....

now i want to make a installer with some other applications...i have

```
myproject.exe
.netframework 3.5
adobeflashplayer.exe
```

now i want to make a single installer that should install these application at once...how should i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding packaging the .NET Framework 3.5 into your setup project, read [Microsoft KB Article 324733](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324733).  In short, you can't do what you asked for.  You can specify .NET as a pre-requisite, and you can detect that the pre-req is missing, but the user must elect to install .NET separately, and must run a separate MSI to install .NET.

About Adobe Flash, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

"You can't do what you asked for." --

Well, at least not with the deployment model offered by Microsoft inside Visual Studio.

Pay $$$ and get InstallShield (or some such) and, oh, spend A LONG TIME learning it, then its cake !